# Loading cordova plugin from the external site -ios

Tags: ios, cordova-2.0.0

From external site , i want to get called my cordova customer plugin.

i used cordovaViewController (cordova 2.0) as web view  and load the webpage by calling loadUrl();
JS of the external website has the following line:
Cordova.exec( onSuccess, onFail, "Navigator","Navigate2",[]);

now once the webpage is get loaded , i want to see the Navigate2 action method get invoked.

i have set up  the custom plugin correctly but this remote call is not calling my action method.

cordova-2.1.0.js would be the problem.

i tried to inject the cordova.js by;

NSString *cordova = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:cordvajsPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

[viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:cordova];

But not working . is there any particular way of doing this. or Cordova is not supporting external website calls.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem cordova-2.2.0 and I resolved changing the cordova.js file (the one for iOS is different from android version!)